# Drupal theme a block with html content

Tags: html, drupal, themes

How do I theme a block with plain HTML content

Following is the code for the content type render

```
function phone_content_type_render($subtype, $conf, $panel_args, $context) {
  $block = new stdClass();
  $block->module = 'support';
  $block->title = '';
  $url = "http://time.com"(assumed url)
  $response = drupal_http_request($url);

$block->content =  render($response->data);


return $block;

}
```

The response->data is an html file.

How can I theme the HTML file to render it with specific style?

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-declare the classes on the HTML content!